# transition-delay doesn't work with ng-class

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

I have a font awesome icon on a button and it switches between `fa-search` and `fa-spinner` icons with `ng-class` (when user types something in the corresponding input, it tries to autocomplete, runs an AJAX request and displays spinner):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i id="metasearch-icon" style="width: 15px;" ng-class="['fa', {'fa-spinner fa-pulse': loadingLocations, 'fa-search': !loadingLocations}]"></i>
  <span class="hidden-xs-inline">Search</span>
</button>
```

[image]

However, with this implementation it blinks too fast and I want to display spinner for at least 0.25s. Thus, I wanted to introduce a `transition-delay`, but it doesn't work:

```
#metasearch-icon.fa-spinner-add,
#metasearch-icon.fa-spinner-remove {
  transition-delay: 0.25s !important;
  transition: 1s linear all !important;
  background: red !important;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Put the property `transition-delay` after declaring the transition.

```css
#metasearch-icon.fa-spinner-add,
#metasearch-icon.fa-spinner-remove {
    transition: 1s linear all !important;
    transition-delay: 0.25s !important;
    background: red !important;
};
```